# How to update "list-item" in SharePoint directory

Tags: c#, sharepoint, listitem

Here is my code for SharePoint.

```
 Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileUrl, bstream, false);
                    isAlreadyExists = false;
                    var file = clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUrl);
                    clientContext.Load(file);
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
                    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItem listItem = file.ListItemAllFields;
                    listItem[Utility.fieldNameSentReceived] = isSentOrReceived;
                    listItem[Utility.fieldNameSentBy] = msg.From.ToString();
                    listItem[Utility.fieldNameReceivedBy] = msg.To.ToString();
                    listItem[Utility.fieldNameSubject] = ((!msg.Subject.Contains("[" + ListCI.Title + "]")) ? "[" + ListCI.Title + "] " : string.Empty) + msg.Subject.ToString();
                    listItem[Utility.fieldNameSentReceivedDateTime] = dt;
                    listItem.Update();
                    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
                    CreateCategoryIfNotExist(emailAddress);
                    SetCategoryToEmail(emailAddress, id);
```

I tried to update directory list-item(Header of directory).
but it throws exception "Column 'SentORReceived' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."

Comment: Are you sure that column `SentORReceived` really exist? It should be internal name of a column. If you used different name when creating the column and then renamed, you need to use the original one. Other columns can be set without any problem?

Comment: Thanks. @LukasNespor.

Comment: So, did it help?

Comment: yes, it helped. @LukasNespor

Comment: I posted it as answer. Can you accept it as the best answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that column `SentORReceived` really exist?

It should be internal name of a column. If you used different name when creating the column and then renamed, you need to use the original one.